# I don't want to get data as strings in array - coffeescript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

Here I am creating an array `data`

```
class_enrollment_data_values = (class_id) ->
  data = []
  $.each $("#class_data_#{class_id}").data('enrollment-count'), (index, value) ->
    data.push("{
                x: #{value},
                y: #{index + 1},
                date: #{$("#class_data_#{class_id}").data('enrollment-dates')[index]}
              }")
  data
```

which is resulting as following data:

`["{ x: 12, y: 1, date: 11/19/18 }", "{ x: 2, y: 2, date: 11/20/18 }"]`

I actually need it as follows i.e. without string quotes:

`[{ x: 12, y: 1, date: 11/19/18 }, { x: 2, y: 2, date: 11/20/18 }]`

Comment: Just omit quotes on push, I guess

Comment: That shouldn't work at all, `x: #{value},` inside a string literal will result in the literal substring `x: #{value},`

Comment: Omitting quotes on push it is resulting in following error:
`SyntaxError: [stdin]:1585:29: unexpected newline`

Answer (score 0):

You push it as a string... Remove - " - in the code.

Comment: After removing quotes I am getting

`SyntaxError: [stdin]:1585:29: unexpected newline`